# JSON and xml which ones to use if a person is writing API in php.

Tags: php, json, xml, performance

JSON and xml which ones to use if a person is writing API in php. Want to know depending upon the storage and efficiency.

Comment: Thanks i think this will help. Wanted to know abit more related to language which i'm using.

Comment: json and XML are similar in performance, json being slightly smaller in size... and XML being more extensible and flexible... both are well supported in php...